# How to make AWS Glue Crawler connection to mongodb

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

We are having trouble getting AWS Glue Crawler to make connection to our mongodb. The mongodb is publically  accessible

But we get the following error

> [cb423c7c-b0ef-4649-92ea-c784ddd4aa96] ERROR : Unable to resolve any
> valid connection (Service: AWSGlueJobExecutor; Status Code: 400; Error
> Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID:
> 9148b2a0-cb4e-41b6-982f-6cdd881b3859; Proxy: null)

Although unsure why this is occuring.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The database name is missing in the URL. The connection URL should be `mongodb://host:port/database`

Comment: Even after including the database name i still get the same `Unable to resolve any valid connection (Service: AWSGlueJobExecutor; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 96f12b72-16e9-407d-a77b-079a1d314b61; Proxy: null)
`

Comment: and yes the database is up and publically available